# Why i'm getting a error using ScriptEngineManager by passing a string formula?

Tags: java

I'm using Java's `ScriptEngineManager` to run some math formulas that will arrive in a string value.

But I'm receiving the following error and I can't find the reason.

```
    private void testFormula(){
    String form ="((15.643333435058594+15.79137191501063+15.432352762204175+15.77764736947019+15.550000190734863)/5-15)-0.6";
    String form2 = "(((13.468705654144287)^0.25)*100)–204.45040893554688";
    try {
        //Debug info
        log.info("[PRE-ENGINE][" + form + "]");

        ScriptEngineManager mgr = new ScriptEngineManager();
        ScriptEngine engine = mgr.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
        form2 = engine.eval(form2).toString();

        //Debug info
        log.info("[RESULT:" + form2 + "]");

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        log.error(ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```

When I run the adobe code by using the string **form1** returns the result without problem.
But when I use the **form2** I'm getting the following error:

```
<eval>:1:33 Expected ; but found error   
 (((13.468705654144287)^0.25)*100)–204.45040893554688
                                 ^ in <eval> at line number 1 at column number 33
```

I don't have any clue by what could be the reason of this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main issue is that the minus sign in the `String` is actually the [Unicode EN Dash](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2013/index.htm), so it cannot be interpreted properly; replace it with the actual minus symbol (`-`) to fix the issue.

Another problem is that `^` is actually the bitwise XOR operator, which does not perform exponentiation. You would need to replace that with `**`.

```js
console.log((((13.468705654144287)**0.25)*100)-204.45040893554688)
```

Comment: Thanks, it was the unicode the problem on the calculation. I made a replace with minus symbol and the formula works.

But the ScriptEngine never recognize the '**' symbol so I change the library for MathParser.org-mXparser and then it works with the ^.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: @JuanEnriqueRiquelme No problem.